# Want to show my android application in mailing list to user

Tags: android, list, show, mailing

I want to launch my application or want to show my application in mailing list if someone clicks on email address from any other app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Mailing list_?? You want your app to handle clicks on email addresses??

Comment: It is like when user clicks on email address android shows a list of all installed application which are used to send email like, gmail, default mail application etc.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the intent filter in your manifest file of your application 
that can something like this

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />     
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

this will make your app appear in sharing list

Comment: I tried it but is not showing my application in the list. Am clicking email address from an email using gmail application.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this lines in your manifest lines and check it.

```
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: still not working... what mime type gmail sends when we click on email address from mail content?